# Static IP address for App Engine app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm currently moving my e-commerce app to Google App Engine. I'm using the PHP Flexible runtime (PHP flex).

One of the transaction requires a call upon my Payment Provider's HTTP API. The problem now, *my Payment Provider requires all caller IP address to be white-listed* beforehand through some out-of-band registration. Registration is very restricted, only accepting a handful of IPv4 address per client.

I know GAE will spawn new instance as needed which will be assigned IP address from a large pool. So registering [a list of address](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) is not an option either.

I know this defeats the purpose of automatic scaling but is there any way I can assign static IP address to my app?

Is there any other way to approach this problem in GAE?

Will launching my app inside VPC helps here?

Comment: As of now, the GAE doesn't have the option to assign a static IP to an application. But you can make use of a [GCP VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/?hl=en) with a [static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) address, and then use it as a proxy for your GAE App might do the task. You can also check for similar discussion here([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145648/assigning-static-ip-address-to-gae-python-project?answertab=votes#tab-top))

Comment: Additionally, there is an ongoing '[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35891948)' in the GCP for assigning static IP address for the GAE. You can make your valuable comments and suggestions there as well.

Comment: @Digil seems the proxy method is the way to go for now. If you would write this as answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, the GAE doesn't have the option to assign a static IP to an application. But you can make use of a [GCP VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/?hl=en) with a [static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) address, and then use it as a proxy for your GAE App might do the task. You can also check for a similar discussion here([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145648/assigning-static-ip-address-to-gae-python-project?answertab=votes#tab-top))